# Python Pandas: How to specify the starting cell position when exporting dataframe to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

When a dataframe is exported from Pandas to Excel using xlsxwriter, it seems to put the table at cell A1 by default.

Is there a way to change this? I don't mind inserting rows and columns to move the table away from A1, as long as it's done programmatically via pandas or xlsxwriter.

In case it helps, here is my code.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'c:\file.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
workbook - writer.book
df.to_excel(writer, index=True, sheet_name ='Sheet1')
```

I couldn't find any XlsxWriter method for inserting rows and columns either.

Comment: The answer from DeepSpace is correct but just to note that this is covered in the XlsxWriter section on [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#handling-multiple-pandas-dataframes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) accepts `startrow` and `startcol` arguments which are zero-based numbers (ie `startrow=1` and `startcol=1` will put the top left cell of the table in cell B2).

> startrow :
>   upper left cell row to dump data frame
>
> startcol :
>   upper left cell column to dump data frame

Comment: How can one do this with the alphanumeric 'A1' cell location instead of `startrow` and `startcol`?

Comment: What if I want to write 3 dataframes of different row lengths to Same Excel Worksheet of an Excelfile? When I give startrow += df1.shape[0] and then supply this argument without a constant no to write the 2nd Dataframe, it displays : SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: @burkesquires `xlsxwriter.utility.xl_col_to_name(integer)` will provide the alphanumeric representation of a 0-based numeric cell identifier. Example: `xlsxwriter.utility.xl_col_to_name(0)` returns `"A"`. This will do the reverse: `xlsxwriter.utility.xl_cell_to_rowcol(f'{string}1')[1]`. Example: If `{string}` is `A`, the returned value is `0`. You can make functions out of these, and work in your preferred representation. Just use the function to map your preferred representation to the required representation at time of.